# Filtering array of objects by object property does not work in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to delete an object from an array by a generated object id.

I've already tried multiple solutions on this and nothing is working.

Handler function:

```
  handleDeleteTask = id => {
    const task = this.state.tasks.find(i => {
      return i.id === id;
    });

    const newTasks = this.state.tasks.splice(task, 1);
    this.setState({ tasks: newTasks });
  };
```

JSX:

```
  {this.state.tasks.map(task => {
          return (
            <Task
              key={task.id}
              task={task.text}
              title={task.title}
              deleteTask={() => this.handleDeleteTask(task.id)}
            />
          );
      })}
```

Comment: you shouldn't ever call splice **on a state object directly**! `this.state.tasks.splice` will mutate the state, instead make a copy `const newTasks = [...this.state.tasks]` then apply the splice on your `newTasks` variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited to reflect the suggestions from comments**

`splice` returns the removed part. You could use filter instead:

```
  handleDeleteTask = id => {

    const newTasks = [...this.state.tasks].filter(x => x.id !== id);
    this.setState({ tasks: newTasks });
  };
```

Or spread the original state, splice the copy and set it as new state

```
  handleDeleteTask = id => {
    const task = this.state.tasks.findIndex(i => {
      return i.id === id;
    })

    const newTasks = [...this.state.tasks]
    newTasks.splice(task, 1)
    this.setState({ tasks: newTasks });
  };
```

Actually this could be written in one single line

```
const removeById = id => this.setState({tasks: [...this.state.tasks].filter(x=> x.id !== id)})
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect. [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the element in the array not the index. Splice takes the index

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you

Comment: yep! probably also can just use findIndex for one iteration rather than 2 scans for the same thing :) Also I'd update each part of your answer to clone the state... even though `filter` returns a new array its generally a good practice to clone the state object so you dont overlook and accidentally mutate state. anyways +1 from me :)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is, `Array.prototype.splice` needs the index of the item you want to delete as the first argument, not the item itself. To find the index instead, change `this.state.tasks.find` to `this.state.tasks.findIndex`.

The second problem is `splice` returns the removed portion of the array, not the new array, so you'd be setting your state to include just the removed item.

Perhaps a simpler approach would be to use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove the undesired item.

```js
handleDeleteTask = id => {
    this.setState({
        tasks: this.state.tasks.filter(it => it.id !== id)
    })
}
```

Comment: Will still be setting state incorrectly though as well as mutating original

Comment: why is that @charlietfl?

Comment: Comment was based on only changing to findIndex ... state would then be what was removed not the spliced array

Comment: Ah you meant to say `state` typo threw me off. The other thing is josh needs to update the answer to splice on a clone of state so you dont mutate directly